# Error: Private key does not satisfy the curve requirements (ie. it is invalid)

Tags: solidity, truffle, ether, testing, kovan

I have a project working fine on truffle but when migrating to Kovan network, Getting the issue "Error: Private key does not satisfy the curve requirements (ie. it is invalid)" project is an exchange. Two account is needed for the testing.

Config file

```
require('babel-polyfill');
require('babel-register');
require('dotenv').config();
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider-privkey')
const privateKeys = process.env.PRIVATE_KEYS || ""

module.exports = {
  
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
     },
     kovan:{
       provider: function(){
         return new HDWalletProvider( 
          privateKeys.split(','),
          `https://kovan.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`
         )
       },
       gas:5000000,
       gasPrice:250000000000,
       network_id:42
     }
  },
  contracts_directory:'./src/contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory:'./src/abis/',

 
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      optimizer: {
         enabled: true,
         runs: 200
       },
    }
  },
};
```

.env file

```
 CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true 
PRIVATE_KEYS="accountOnePrivateKey,accountTwoPrivateKey"
INFURA_API_KEY=62f4-----------------
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You need INFURA_PROJECT_ID instead of INFURA_API_KEY in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of the .env file and make sure they are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `truffle-hdwallet-provider-privkey` instead of `@truffle/hdwallet-provider`. Changing it to `@truffle/hdwallet-provider` solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was in node_modules.

I had to delete them, and then run

```
npm i
```